# .htaccess file: facebots exceptions with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/1.1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/1.0 [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !Facebot [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ https://www.example.com [R,NC]
```

I have this .htaccess file code. It should be allowing facebook bots to get pictures but it does't work? Any idea why ?

Comment: RewriteRule ^image\.jpg$ image.php [L]   can you try this  or this  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "facebookexternalhit/1.1|facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com)|Facebot" [NC]

Comment: after using the second code it gives me: Internal Server Error 500.
and using the first code stops all images of being opened

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php) [NC]
adding this line also makes Internal Server Error 500

Comment: SetEnvIfNoCase Referer "^(http|https)://.*facebook.*" whitelist  have you tried this to white list images

Comment: Internal Server Error... the idea is nobody except bots to be able to hotlink.. I m almost sure errors come because of hosting company but there is no documentation how to do this on their docs.

Comment: check  on this  hope it help you https://forum.ait-pro.com/forums/topic/facebook-bot-facebook-externalhit_uatext-php-facebook-bot-403-error/

Comment: I just tested that conditions on a test machine and they just worked, they don't caused any error and the redirect worked fine, so it must be another thing. Did you put the `RewriteEngine on`? Do you have more configurations in the .htaccess file?

Comment: I have rewrite engine on and i havent other script+ code works except the line that gives facebot ability to get pictures.

Comment: I reread the comments and noticed that I misunderstood it, you only get error 500 after trying the suggestion, which has a syntax error. Try replacing all user agent conditions with only this one: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|Facebot) [NC]`

Comment: I tested it and it works perfectly. Thx a lot you are the best. Also it works with other conditions but it should be the first one

Comment: You're welcome, since it solved your problem I'll put it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is how the user agent rules were written, you can use this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(facebookexternalhit|Facebot) [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ https://www.example.com [R,NC]
```

The new condition match any user agent that neither contains "facebookexternalhit" or "Facebot", this have the advantage that if the user agent is changed slightly (for example, the version change to 1.2) it will still works.